# How to initialize quarto panel in RStudio for an existing project?

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I wonder how one usually creates a quarto-website-github project.

I can either choose to create a `version control` (e.g. github) project or a `quarto project`.

When I create a version-control-github project, I automatically have the git Render button.

When I create a quarto-website project, I automatically have the Render button for quarto websites.

How to get both?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good sequence. It's best to create a repo on GitHub (can be empty), then start a version-control project from GitHub and synchronize that. Copy or create all necessary files for a bookdown (`_output.yml`, `_bookdown.yml` etc.) or quarto (`_quarto.yml` etc.) project manually. Then simply restart RStudio. The panel bottons will appear after restart.

Then we have both, for a bookdown like this

[image]

and for a quarto website like that

[image]

Although I don't understand why this is not the case from the start. Why can't we initialize a bookdown-git-project or a quarto-git-project.